Cannot read custom property - TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'
I am trying to implement session-based authentication system with using Express.js + TypeScript.
I got the problem below in my console while I cannot see any errors in my code.
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/users/authController.ts:21:17 - error TS2339: Property 'loggedIn' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.

21     req.session.loggedIn = true;
                   ~~~~~~~~
src/controllers/users/authController.ts:22:17 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'.

22     req.session.user = user;
                   ~~~~

    at createTSError (/Users/apensia/dev/letha-api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.0.0_@types+node@20.14.11_typescript@5.5.3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:587:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/apensia/dev/letha-api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.0.0_@types+node@20.14.11_typescript@5.5.3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:591:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/apensia/dev/letha-api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.0.0_@types+node@20.14.11_typescript@5.5.3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:921:36)
    at Object.compile (/Users/apensia/dev/letha-api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.0.0_@types+node@20.14.11_typescript@5.5.3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1189:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/apensia/dev/letha-api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.0.0_@types+node@20.14.11_typescript@5.5.3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1295:42)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/apensia/dev/letha-api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.0.0_@types+node@20.14.11_typescript@5.5.3/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1298:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)

What I am trying to do
I am trying to make authentication system with session-based with using express-session and connect-mongo package.
Dependencies
# package.json

"devDependencies": {
    # omitted...
    "@types/connect-mongo": "^3.1.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4",
    "ts-node": "10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
    },
"dependencies": {       
    "connect-mongo": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.8.0",
}

Relevant Codes
// This file is for module merging of express-session package so that I can personally include data that I want to put in my session data.

// src/@types/libs/express-session/index.d.ts

import "express-session";

declare module "express-session" {
  export interface SessionData {
    user: { [key: string]: any };
    loggedIn: boolean;
  }
}


// This is my main Express.js server init file 

import "dotenv/config";
import connectDB from "./db";
import express, { Application } from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import helmet from "helmet";
import session from "express-session";
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import { specs, swaggerUi } from "./swagger.config";
import { userRouter, reviewRouter, authRouter } from "./routers";

const app: Application = express();
const PORT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? process.env.PORT : 4001;

// DB Connection
connectDB();

// Misc
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Session
const SESSION_SECRET_KEY = process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY as string;
app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    secret: SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: 60 * 5 },
    store: MongoStore.create({}),
  })
);

I feel like TypeError is coming mainly from ts-node but don't know where to start to fix.

Based on the sample from this question, you should add export {}; in the end of the file that extend express-session, instead of export interface SessionData.

@YongShun Unfortunately that did not work. I feel like ts-node's types are making collision with the current libraries.

Possibly you may refer to this question too. Aside from that, I think it is better not to modify the file from the package "src/@types/libs/express-session/index.d.ts" directly, when upgrading this package in the future, your changes may lost. You should have another index.d.ts in your project and specify the directory of your index.d.ts in the typeRoots in the tsconfig.json based on the first link I shared. Fingers crossed.

@YongShun Type definition file inside of "src/@types/libs/express-session/index.d.ts" is actually I created manually and I added those in typeRoots in tsconfig.json as [./src/@types/**/*.d.ts].
